# SwiftUI - VStack not filling entire screen when placed in NavigationView

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

It seems like when placed in a NavigationView, VStacks won't fill the entire vertical space. Or maybe I'm doing something wrong?

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("HEY")
        }
        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
        .background(.gray)
    }
    .navigationBarTitle("Reçu", displayMode: .inline)
}
```

I also customized `UINavigationBar` to give it some color and set `navigationBarTitle` to inline.

I tried 2 workarounds:

- `.frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: Alignment.topLeading)`
- `.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)`

The first one fills more vertical space, but not all of it.

[image]

Comment: Hey, @sohomang, before answering your question, let me ask what would you like to achieve? Maybe a colored background? Or maybe you want your views to start from the top and come down?

Comment: @MarkMoeykens Both, actually! I'd like this NavigationView to have a fixed background color. Stacking `.background(myColor)` to the NavigationView didn't cut it. That's why I tried putting it on the VStack.

Comment: I'm having the very same issue, did you find any solution for that weird space in the top of a VStack inside NavigationView?

Answer (score 5):

It looks like there are two navigation views added to your view hierarchy.

- If the parent view has a `NavigationView` and you are going into child view using `NavigationLink` then you don't have to add a `NavigationView` to your child view it has automatically added.
- If you are directly setting new `rootView` for your `UIHostingController` then add `NavigationView` into that new `rootView`.

Answer (score 1):

In order to have a background color for your view I suggest you go for the `ZStack` view:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Color.gray                
            }
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            .navigationBarTitle("Reçu", displayMode: .inline)
        }
    }
}
```

You can even create you custom view (to reuse wherever you want) that takes a colour as a parameter:

```
struct BgColorView<Content>: View where Content: View{
    private let color: Color
    private let content: () -> Content

    init(color: Color, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.color = color
        self.content = content
    }
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            color.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            content()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            BgColorView(color: Color.green) {
                Text("Hello world!")
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Reçu", displayMode: .inline)
        }
    }
}
```

For the second issue, it strictly depends on your needs. The easiest way to have content aligned top-left is using the `Spacer` view.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            BgColorView(color: Color.green) {
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Hello world!")
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Reçu", displayMode: .inline)
        }
    }
}
```

But again, it depends on what you're trying yo get.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're currently setting the `navigationBarTitle` of  your `NavigationView`. However, if you remove the `navigationBarTitle` on the list that might remove the space you're trying to clean up. See this other stack overflow answer on how to do that:
[How to remove the default Navigation Bar space in SwiftUI NavigiationView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57517803/how-to-remove-the-default-navigation-bar-space-in-swiftui-navigiationview)

This is Apple's official tutorial, where they also put the `navigationBarTitle` on the List instead of the actual `NavigationView`:
https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/building-lists-and-navigation#set-up-navigation-between-list-and-detail

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample that shows you how to switch a custom view or screen:

```
struct MyView: View {
    @State var isActive = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Button(action: {
                        self.isActive = true
                    }) {
                        Text("Hey")
                    }
                }
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center)
                .background(Color.blue)
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            }
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: self.$isActive, content: {
            Text("This is full screen View or custom view")
        })
            .navigationBarTitle("Reçu", displayMode: .inline)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all thank you [Niley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7763437/nilay) for pointing the issue, but there is one case missing:
What if I want a new NavigationView in ChildNavigation View?
The answer is just to add these three lines in content view of navigation view:

> .navigationBarTitle(Text(""), displayMode: .inline)
>
> .navigationBarHidden(true)
>
> .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)

```
NavigationView{
    VStack{} or HStack{} or ZStack{}
    .navigationBarTitle(Text(""), displayMode: .inline)
    .navigationBarHidden(true)
    .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
}
```