# How to navigate from a subview of a TabView back to the TabView in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, swiftui

In SwiftUI a TabView must be the root view. You, therefore, cannot use a NavigationLink to navigate to a TabView. So say for instance I have four screens in my app.

Screen A is a TabView that holds Screen B and Screen C. 
Screen B is a List that has a NavigationLink to take you to a list item details (Screen D)
Screen C is an information view (it's not important in the question)
Screen D is a list item details screen, you must first navigate to screen b to get here. Screen D, however, has a button that should perform a network action in a ViewModel, and then take you to ScreenA upon completion.

How can Screen D navigation back two levels to the root screen (Screen A)?

Comment: If ScreenA is TabView{ScreenB|ScreenC} and ScreenB > ScreenD then I don't see two level navigation, did I miss anything? The scenario is not clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An effective way to "pop" to your root view would be to utilize the `isDetailLink` modifier on the `NavigationLink` that is used for navigating.

By default, `isDetailLink` is `true`. This modifier is used for a variety of view containers, like on iPad, where the detail view would appear on the right side.

Setting `isDetailLink` to `false` means that the view will be pushed on top of the `NavigationView` stack, and can also be pushed off.

Along with setting `isDetailLink` to false on `NavigationLink`, pass the `isActive` binding to each child destination view. When you want to pop to the root view, set the value to `false` and it will pop everything off:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ScreenA: View {
    @State var isActive : Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(
                destination: ScreenB(rootIsActive: self.$isActive),
                isActive: self.$isActive
            ) {
                Text("ScreenA")
            }
            .isDetailLink(false)
            .navigationBarTitle("Screen A")
        }
    }
}

struct ScreenB: View {
    @Binding var rootIsActive : Bool

    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: ScreenD(shouldPopToRootView: self.$rootIsActive)) {
            Text("Next screen")
        }
        .isDetailLink(false)
        .navigationBarTitle("Screen B")
    }
}

struct ScreenD: View {
    @Binding var shouldPopToRootView : Bool

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Last Screen")
            Button (action: { self.shouldPopToRootView = false } ){
                Text("Pop to root")
            }
        }.navigationBarTitle("Screen D")
    }
}
```

Comment: How would this work with the MVVM setup though? Each screen in swift should have a ViewModel. So say once your at screen D, you press a button that performs a network call in the viewmodel. Then when that network call completes and is successful, is when you should pop to the root view

Comment: Good but when ScreenB showed, I would like TabView navigation bar must be hide - how to do it?

Comment: @IgorCova for hiding the tab bar you can place TabView inside NavigationView. 1.NavigationView -> Link -> TabView screen -> Every Tab can contain NavigationLink, not View.

Answer (score 2):

I did a trick like this, worked for me.

In SceneDelegate.swift, I modified auto generated code.

```swift
let contentView = ContentView()

if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
   let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
   // Trick here.
   let nav = UINavigationController(
       rootViewController: UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
    )
    // I embedded this host controller inside UINavigationController
    //  window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
    window.rootViewController = nav
    self.window = window
    window.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

**Note**: I expected embedding `TabView` inside `NavigationView` would do the same job, but did not work, it was the reason of doing this trick.

I assume, `contentView` is the View that you want to pop to (the one includes TabView)

Then in any view navigated from that view, you can call

```swift
extension View {
    func popToRoot() {
        guard let rootNav = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController else { return }
        rootNav.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
    }
}

// Assume you eventually came to this view.
struct DummyDetailView: View {

    var body: some View {

        Text("DetailView")
           .navigationBarItems(trailing:
               Button("Pop to root view") {
                   self.popToRoot()
               }
           )
    }
}

// EDIT: Requested sample with a viewModel
struct DummyDetailViewWithViewModel: View {

    var viewModel: SomeViewModel = SomeViewModel()

    var body: some View {        
        Button("Complete Order!!") {
            viewModel.completeOrder(success: { _ in
                print("Order Completed")
                self.popToRoot()
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How would this work with the MVVM setup though? Each screen in swift should have a ViewModel. So say once your at screen D, you press a button that performs a network call in the viewmodel. Then when that network call completes and is successful, is when you should pop to the root view

Comment: Does not matter where you call this. For ex: you tapped a button & made network call.
You can give a success callback back to the view you performed operation. so you may trigger that method there.

Comment: ;( You can hide it if you want. But if you want to push to a detail view, you gotta be in the navigation view, this is how it works

Comment: if you want to get rid of the navigation bar, I recommend [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57517803/how-to-remove-the-default-navigation-bar-space-in-swiftui-navigiationview)

Answer (score 2):

I have resolved this with `self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()`. This is the method that is called to bring back to View of Navigation Root. Here, TestView is ScreenA, ItemList is ScreenB, InfoView is ScreenC and ItemDetails is ScreenD.

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestView: View {
    @State private var currentTab: Tab = .list
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $currentTab){
            ItemList()
                .tabItem{
                    Text("List")
            }
            .tag(Tab.list)
            .navigationBarHidden(false)
            InfoView()
                .tabItem{
                    Text("Info")
            }
            .tag(Tab.info)
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
        }
    }
}

struct ItemList: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            NavigationView{
                List {
                    NavigationLink(destination: ItemDetails()){
                        Text("Item")
                    }
                    NavigationLink(destination: ItemDetails()){
                        Text("Item")
                    }
                    NavigationLink(destination: ItemDetails()){
                        Text("Item")
                    }
                    NavigationLink(destination: ItemDetails()){
                        Text("Item")
                    }
                }.navigationBarTitle("Item List")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct InfoView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("This is information view")
    }
}

struct ItemDetails: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>
    @State private var loading = false
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Text("Connecting...")
                .font(.title)
                .offset(y: -150)
                .pulse(loading: self.loading)
            VStack {
                Text("This is Item Details")
                Button("Connect"){
                    self.loading = true
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
                        self.loading = false
                        self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                    }
                }.padding()
            }
        }
    }
}

enum Tab {
    case list, info
}

extension View {
    func pulse(loading: Bool) -> some View {
        self
            .opacity(loading ? 1 : 0)
            .animation(
                Animation.easeInOut(duration: 0.5)
                    .repeatForever(autoreverses: true)
        )

    }
}
```