# Hide Navigation Bar after NavigationLink is Tapped but keeping back button

Tags: swift, button, swiftui, navigationbar

I have two different views, one with a NavigationView and another one that i want without NavigationView but since i put it in a NavigationLink I can still see it with a button to go back to the first view.
Here's the code:

```
struct MainView: View {
    var body: some View {

    NavigationView {
        NavigationLink(destination: SecondView()) {
            Text("Go to SecondView")

        .navigationBarTitle("MainView")
        }
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    var body: some View {

    Text("This is the SecondView")
}
```

I want to hide the Navigation Bar in the Second View but leaving a button to go back. I don't know if i can keep the button that was already displayed in the Navigation Bar or should i make a new one...in this case how can I add one to go back to the previous view?

Comment: You can refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57518324/7420795

Comment: Thank you so much! I made a binding property that changes when the view of navigationlink appears and works perfectly

Comment: By the way do you know how can I add a back button now that the navigation Bar is gone?

Comment: You can add a custom button for this. var btnBack : some View { Button(action: {
        self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }) {
            HStack {
            Image("ic_back") // set image here
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                Text("Go back")
            }
        }
    }
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57594164/7420795

Comment: Amazing, thank you for helping! I actauuly saw that thread before but I couldn't understand how that was working