# SwiftUI go to another view from UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit

I have a project which built with SwiftUI and to be able to use stripe I am now integrating UIKit into this SwiftUI project. This is an example of what I want to do. I want to go to another view from UIKit.
Here is my content view in SwiftUI. If you copy paste this code it will work on your xcode also.

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ViewControllerWrapper(controller: MyViewController.init())
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

class MyViewController: UIViewController{
    lazy var goToAnotherViewButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        button.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 22)
        button.setTitle("Go", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(goToAnotherView), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [goToAnotherViewButton])
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.spacing = 20
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(stackView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            stackView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalToSystemSpacingAfter: view.leftAnchor, multiplier: 2),
            view.rightAnchor.constraint(equalToSystemSpacingAfter: stackView.rightAnchor, multiplier: 2),
            stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalToSystemSpacingBelow: view.topAnchor, multiplier: 2),
        ])
    }
    
    @objc
    func goToAnotherView() {
            //from this function I want to go to Another View
        }
}

struct ViewControllerWrapper: UIViewControllerRepresentable{
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ViewControllerWrapper>) -> UIViewController {
        guard let controller=controller else {
            return UIViewController()
        }
        return controller
    }
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ViewControllerWrapper>) {
    }
    let controller:UIViewController?
    typealias UIViewControllerType = UIViewController
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create instance of UIHostingController and push this controller to navigation controller.

Example:

```
struct ContentView1: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView(content: {
            ViewControllerWrapper(controller: MyViewController.init())
        })
        .navigationTitle("View")
        .navigationBarTitle("Text")
    }
}

struct AnotherView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("AnotherView In Swiftui")
            .font(.title)
    }
}

struct ContentView1_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView1()
    }
}

class MyViewController: UIViewController{
    lazy var goToAnotherViewButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        button.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 22)
        button.setTitle("Go", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(goToAnotherView), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [goToAnotherViewButton])
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.spacing = 20
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(stackView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            stackView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalToSystemSpacingAfter: view.leftAnchor, multiplier: 2),
            view.rightAnchor.constraint(equalToSystemSpacingAfter: stackView.rightAnchor, multiplier: 2),
            stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalToSystemSpacingBelow: view.topAnchor, multiplier: 2),
        ])
    }
    
    @objc
    func goToAnotherView() {
        //from this function I want to go to Another View
        let vc = UIHostingController(rootView: AnotherView())
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
}

struct ViewControllerWrapper: UIViewControllerRepresentable{
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ViewControllerWrapper>) -> UIViewController {
        guard let controller=controller else {
            return UIViewController()
        }
        return controller
    }
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ViewControllerWrapper>) {
    }
    let controller:UIViewController?
    typealias UIViewControllerType = UIViewController
}
```

Comment: thank you for the solution. when I add navigationview it adds extra space to the top. now i am trying to solve this problem. thanks again

Comment: @neco Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57517803/how-to-remove-the-default-navigation-bar-space-in-swiftui-navigationview