# SwiftUI vertical alignment with Navigation view

Tags: swiftui

I try to align content on top of page.
It works but as soon as I add a NavigationView, it doesn't work anymore.

```
import SwiftUI
struct Stats: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {    // <- OK without navigation view
            VStack {
                Text("Stats")
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Seems a basic problem, but didn't succeed to work it out :(
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove the default Navigation Bar space in SwiftUI NavigationView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57517803/how-to-remove-the-default-navigation-bar-space-in-swiftui-navigationview)

Comment: Thanks Emilio, that was it. I did try .navigationBarHidden(true) but I applied it to the navigation view, and it must be applied to the Stack inside the navigation view !

Answer (score 2):

Regards to Emilio's réponse, here is the solution.

```
import SwiftUI
struct Stats: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("Stats")
                Spacer()
            }
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
        }
    }
}
```

Take care to apply navigationBarHidden to the Stack and not NavigationView.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to hide NavigationBar.

```
 NavigationView {   
             VStack {
                 Text("Stats")
                 Spacer()
                               }
                     .navigationBarTitle("")
                     .navigationBarHidden(true)
             
         }
```