# NavigationView adding top padding

Tags: swiftui, navigationview

I have a very simple view, a background color and some text. But when I wrap it in a NavigationView I'm getting unwanted spacing at the top of the view. How can I eliminate this? (I want the Navigation as I will be adding NavigationLinks)

e.g.

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(
                    LinearGradient(
                        gradient: Gradient(colors: [.indigo, .purple]),
                        startPoint: .bottom,
                        endPoint: .top
                    )
                )
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            
            VStack {
                Text("Test")
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove the default Navigation Bar space in SwiftUI NavigationView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57517803/how-to-remove-the-default-navigation-bar-space-in-swiftui-navigationview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The space is reserved for the title, so if you set the navigation bar title display mode to `.inline`, then it should reduce that space.

```swift
NavigationView {
    ZStack {
        /* ... */
    }
    .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
}
```

Comment: I fixed it with: .navigationBarHidden(true)

Answer (score 6):

You can fix this by using `.navigationBarHidden(true)`.

However, `.navigationBarHidden(true)` will be deprecated in the new version of iOS, so you can use `.toolbar(.hidden)` instead.